# MVC how to disable the required validation for some controls

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am creating a web application using MVC 4.

I have a few properties in my view model that has been decorated with the required attribute as shown,

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "StateRequiredMessage", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Agency.CreateEdit))]
public int? PostalAddressStateId { get; set; }
```

but then in my view, depending on what the user selects from a tick box, I disable some of the properties that have been tagged as required.

I disable the controls using jQuery:

```
$("#PostalAddressStateId").attr("disabled", true);
```

Then when I try to save, it says the value is required. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
ModelState.Remove("PostalAddressStateId");
```

at your controller

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    PostalAddressStateId.Attributes.Remove("Required");
```

You might need to set a boolean in javascript and send it back to the controller, the required attribute impacts your server side code as well.

In my opinion, a field like this shouldn't be marked as required unless it's always required. If this is in a viewmodel, then I'd  probably remove the attribute and replace it with a custom attribute or some other way of determining that it's filled in when it must be and not filled in when it's not required.

More about attributecollections here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.attributecollection.remove(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I would check out MVC Foolproof Validation on CodePlex. You could use the RequiredIfTrue attribute that comes with Foolproof to solve the issue above.

http://foolproof.codeplex.com/

Comment: that looks great, but I wonder if it can do multiple requiredIfTrue atrributes to the one properties.. you know if I can disable the validation using jquery?

Comment: You can definitely point multiple RequiredIfTrue attributes at the value of one property. For instance, if you have a boolean property like "MailingAddressRequired", you can have multiple RequiredIfTrue attributes look at MailingAddressRequired. You could probably disable the validation through JQuery, maybe by targeting the data-val attribute in the <input> element that is produced by ASP. Haven't tried that though.